# Does markdown work in comments in "needs ♦ moderator attention" Flag dialog?

Tags: discussion, markdown, flags

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Markdown is supported in flags these days. It uses the same "mini Markdown" renderer used for comments.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214270/133242