# Supported Markdown for Flag Text does not Match Supported Comment Markdown

Tags: feature-request, bug, flags, markdown, magic-links

[This answer from 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214270/1099857) states that:

> flags are now rendered using the same "mini-markdown" renderer used for comments.

The [help center on comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) includes a list of shorthand links (I've linked Stack Overflow's help center here because I used [mre] in the flag which *is* supported comment markdown there). [The answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214270/1099857) also mentions specific shorthand links like:

> [gardening.se] or [su]

However, it does not appear that all of these links are supported, nor are other supported comment markdown features like `[tag:]`:
[image: self-removed comment flag with unparsed markdown reading: "Test markdown parse [tour], [mre], [tag:pandas], [ask]"]

---

Is it no longer correct that flags are parsed "using the same "mini-markdown" renderer used for comments"? Or is this a bug and these mini-markdown shortcuts should be supported?

If it is intentional that flags use a different subset of markdown than comments can it be documented somewhere what markdown is supported in flags and what is not?

---

To be clear, I am *not* arguing the usefulness of these shortcuts. I am simply asking *if* this markdown should be supported and if they should not can we document what exactly *is* supported in flags.