# Can custom flags have markdown?

Tags: support, flags

If I **use** `markdown` *formatting* in a custom flag, will it render, or will it just look awful?

I am asking this question so that no one else will have to flag random posts, and then retract their flag to find out.

Comment: "[Could we have markdown in comments in the Flag dialog, pretty please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83149/271271) and "[Supported Markdown for Flag Text does not Match Supported Comment Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380177/271271)"

Answer (score 16):

## Yes. Proof:

> [image: Proof]

Markdown:

```
[does](https://www.example.com) *markdown* **work** `in` flags
```

Comment: Fun fact: Moderators cannot respond to you with markdown.

Comment: @Laurel you mean what we see in our flag summary? Well, if needed mod can super ping the user in chat.

Comment: This doesn't actually prove it. In fact, it only proves that one particular view does render the markdown. It would be entirely possible that this view renders the markdown, but the moderator flag dashboard doesn't. However, it does, at least these days, render in the mod view. **You are always safe sticking with "mini-markdown", the same subset of markdown that is allowed in comments** (excepting quicklinks). Even if markdown *doesn't* render in a particular view, mods should be comfortable enough with the syntax that they will be able to understand what you are trying to say anyway.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack Yes, when [marking a flag as helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52eWo.png) or declined, a moderator can send a short message which will be shown in the user's flag history, but it's rendered in plain text.